# DNN5 account login module doesn't show the username and password label

Tags: authentication, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5

Hello every body,

I have a very strange issue with the account login module using dotnetnuke 5.6.8.

I have to create a new web site, every thing was ok before i added localization for three languages.

```
    For two languages i have no problems with the account login module, but whit the Nederlands (Belgie) the module doesn't show the username and the password label. I have added the old values in the Login.ascx.resx files but nothing change :( !
```

Here is the link to the issue (text label is empty !) :

http://portal.b2boost.eu/ipt-vincotte/Home/tabid/887/language/nl-BE/Default.aspx?returnurl=/ipt-vincotte/en-gb/search.aspx

I use dnn 5 every day but it's the first time i got this issue, if somebody have any Idea  ...

Thanks for help.

Comment: Is your nl-be resource file containing an entry with an empty translation? Ithink it could cause this issue.

Comment: Thanks for help, they are any empty translation, i have fill all values in the resx files ...

Comment: once you change resource file, you have to go to host settings and restart the application and clear the cache from there to make sure latest files are loaded

Comment: I have a lot of websites on this host, i can not restart it any time ! I have change the file from the portal not in the server files, i did it many times before and this issue never hapened. My be i have to delete the resx file for this language pack and retranslate.